# Set an array from class and get him outside a class

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I would create an array with ID posts from inside a function, and get him outside the class.
My code:

```html
<?php 
class cat_widget extends WP_Widget {
private $newHomePost = array();  
 
 function widget($args, $instance){ 
      //...

      foreach($img_ids as $img_id) { 
  if (is_numeric($img_id)) {
   $this->setNewHomePost($newsCounter,$post->ID);
   $newsCounter++;
            
            //...
        }
      }
    }
 function setNewHomePost($num, $value){ 
  $newHomePost[$num] = $value;
 }
 function getNewHomePost(){ 
        return "ID: ".$this->newHomePost[0];
    }
}

$testA = new cat_widget();
echo $testA->getNewHomePost();
?>
```

I receive on screen this resuld:
ID:
(without the id)

But if I insert inside setNewHomePost() an echo for the array, I'll obtain correctly the array but inside and not outside class.

```html
     function setNewHomePost($num, $value){ 
      $newHomePost[$num] = $valore;
      echo $newHomePost[0];
     }
```

So seem that the array works fine inside the "function widget", but doesn't works outside it.
Can someone help me, please?

Comment: This code does not work if used out of context Wordpress

Answer (score 2):

```
function setNewHomePost($num, $value){ 
    $newHomePost[$num] = $value;
}
```

This creates a [*local*](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) variable named `$newHomePost`, setting a value at an index and returning.  Once it returns, the local variable disappears. From the linked manual page:

> Any variable used inside a function is by default limited to the local function scope.

You want to set the class member [property](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php) `newHomePost` instead:

```
function setNewHomePost($num, $value) { 
    $this->newHomePost[$num] = $value;
}
```

**Update**

This is how you currently have the get method defined:

```
function getNewHomePost() {
    return "ID: " . $this->newHomePost[0];
}
```

I suspect you're still fiddling with this and trying to get it to work.  If you really want to just only ever return the 0'th index, try something like this instead:

```
function getNewHomePost() {
    return isset($this->newHomePost[0]) ? $this->newHomePost[0] : null;
}
```

When building a class remember that you cannot make any assumptions about what order your public methods can be called from another object or calling code (even if the calling code itself exists inside of the class. The methods are public, meaning anything can call them). The code above assumes nothing in that you do not have to call `addNewHomePost` prior to `getNewHomePost`.  I imagine if you look in your logs you may see a few `Notice: Undefined index..` type errors.

Also be sure to check on the calling side:

```
$myClass = new cat_widget;
$myClass->setNewHomePost(0, 'my new home post!');

$homePost = $myClass->getNewHomePost();
echo $homePost ? $homePost : 'None';
```

I think a better getter method would probably look like this:

```
function getNewHomePost($i) {
    return isset($this->newHomePost[$i]) ? $this->newHomePost[$i] : null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Now, how can I use this variable from outside of class?

`$test = new className();
echo $test->getNewHomePost();`

to outside of class doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @watcher. I tried your suggest, but if I insert `getNewHomePost()` outside the `function widget` this doesn't works and receive only `ID:` without id number (ex ID: 567).

If I insert `getNewHomePost()` inside the `function widget` this works fine and print `ID:` with id number (ex ID: 567).
So I would that `getNewHomePost()` works also outside from `function widget`. Any suggestion, please?